# Xbox trigger / analog stick sensitivity

Tags: xbox-360, controllers, grand-theft-auto-v

Along with the rest of the world I've been playing through GTA5. In my attempts to drive "well" I've been taking advantage of the sensitivity of the triggers and analog sticks.

However, I can't quite work out how many sensor 'points' there are. The trigger I think has only about two (half down or all down) as I seem to only be able to get the car to drive at a semi-slow speed or full throttle.

The analog sticks seem to be more sensitive, sometimes I'm able to get very gradual turning circles in the car.

Is anyone able to provide some more detail about the accuracy of the analog sticks and triggers in GTA 5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The triggers of an Xbox 360 controller report values usually interpreted as between zero and one. There's a fairly wide variety in what can be reported by the controller, but it is certainly more than three possible positions (I expect there to be around fifteen to twenty).

GTA5 is an arcade game, not a driving simulator. It would be understandable if they only had "slow" and "fast" options for the throttle, though for myself I can't say I've noticed this.

Comment: Does the "around fifteen to twenty" estimation count for the tilt of the analog sticks too?

Comment: I don't think anyone would design a console game expecting people to be that precise with their inputs, but yes. The numbers reported are certainly incrementing in something of the order of 1/20.

Comment: and given that the input would be binary then 4 to 8 bits allocated for the signals would be reasonable

Comment: I don't know about the physical controller, but the XInput API provides one byte of range for each trigger, which gives 256 possible positions: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/microsoft.directx_sdk.reference.xinput_gamepad%28v=vs.85%29.aspx